# Mac turtlesim dependent xorg-xcb-util failure

Tags: ros, wxwidgets, turtlesim, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New mac user to ROS.  Installed on 10.6, with help from ROSAnswers.
Now going through tutorial.  Trying to install dependants for turtlesim.

Get error when it tries to install xorg-xcb-util needed for wxWidgets-python.

Help?

```
AJS-24-iMac:turtlesim ajs$ rosdep install turtlesim
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#Packages
sudo port install wxWidgets-python
}}}
--->  Computing dependencies for wxWidgets-python
--->  Dependencies to be installed: gtk2 pango cairo xorg-xcb-util shared-mime-info xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXdamage xorg-damageproto xorg-libXi xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto mesa makedepend xorg-dri2proto xorg-glproto xorg-libXmu xorg-libXt xorg-libsm xorg-libice
--->  Building xorg-xcb-util
Log for xorg-xcb-util is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_x11_xorg-xcb-util/main.log
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
rosdep install ERROR:
rosdep script failed with stderr 
{{{
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install xorg-xcb-util
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: gtk2 pango cairo xorg-xcb-util shared-mime-info xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXdamage xorg-damageproto xorg-libXi xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto mesa makedepend xorg-dri2proto xorg-glproto xorg-libXmu xorg-libXt xorg-libsm xorg-libice
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.

}}}
AJS-24-iMac:turtlesim ajs$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10537/mac-turtlesim-dependent-xorg-xcb-util-failure/) by [ajs](https://answers.ros.org/users/808/ajs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity in > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0